# JavaScript - object changed after calling function without return, how?

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

There's a JavaScript function, lets call it "primary", it contains another function inside, name it "secondary".

The logic is that primary gets an object, passes the object to secondary then secondary adds another key/value into given object, finally primary returns the object.

```
function primary(objA) {
    function secondary(obj, key, value) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    let key = 'newkey';
    let value = 'newvalue';
    secondary(objA, key, value);
    return objA;
}
```

Surprisingly, `objA` is changed.

```
{
    key: "value",
    newkey: "newvalue"
}
```

My question is, how is the secondary function changing obj without returning the modified object!?

Is it because secondary is in the scope of primary? I need a complete explanation please.

Comment: Isn't it because the object is passed by reference? So the "JSON" is changed when `secondary` is called.

Comment: *"Surprisingly, obj is changed."* Why would it surprise you that if you pass in object A and then change it, that after that object A is changed?

Comment: Mutating an object will be visible to any part of the code that uses that object. The objects are not copied when you pass them along.

Comment: @Tomalak well, I'm not that much into JavaScript, I'm a C guy :D so basically it's like passing a pointer and waiting for object to be changed!? that was easier than I expected

Comment: Additionally, there is no JSON in this question. I've removed all references to it. JSON always is a string and you are not dealing with strings here.

Comment: @BrianSP try debugging your function in browser. You'll better understand why it is being changed

Comment: @BrianSP Yes, all parameter passing in JS happens by reference, except for primitive types (number, string, boolean), those are passed by value.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks, that helped a lot, sorry for duplication.

Comment: Watch out, dates are not primitive types in JS, this can bite you if you are not careful.

Comment: @Tomalak noted.